# About python sqlite3 order by

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-order-by

Now, I have a study about python sqlite3 database. I think it is very simple problem but not allow next step. Could help me?

There is print OK on vscode terminal, but not revised to DB file. I'm searching several times but I can not fix it.

**If I execute the code, it not sorting on DB files.**

```py
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('sqliteDB1.db')

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM member")

temp123 = cursor. fetchall()

print(temp123)

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM member ORDER BY -code")

temp321 = cursor.fetchall()

conn.commit

print(temp321)

conn.close()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the exact error or problem?

Comment: I`m sorry it is not reflected in DB file. If i print on vscode, it is OK. But if i open the DB file, the file is not sorting.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `select` statement just returns data from a database, it will not modify it. Moreover, tables in SQL databases are inherently unordered sets. They have no intrinsic value, and you should **never** rely on the order of the rows that happens to be returned unless you explicitly sort it with an `order by` clause.